# Profile pages returning a 500 error page across entire network

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

> **Looks fixed now!**

Getting 500 errors on all* the profile pages, on all the main (non-meta) SE websites:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

I know you're fixing it, but I'm just curious what happened?

`*`: well, I cannot reproduce it on stackexchange.com, maybe there are other exceptions, but something got fishy anyways.

Comment: Meta profiles are opening.

Comment: I can see my SO and Meta.SE profile.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, it's working again. :)

Comment: You the man... I am able to open everything fine.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You came late to the party. `:D`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was a bad roll out of DB migrations + code at the same time. DB migrations happen when meta is built. So it was a case of old (pre-migration) code running against new DB schema. The issue fixed itself once everything was deployed to all servers across all tiers (meta & sites).

Rest assured, The Wheel of Blame has been spun.

Comment: Thank you for **not** putting a meme in your post.